Telegram Mini app - Avoid open multiple instance
I have the problem with my Telegram Mini app. When user open my app directly, every time they press the link, the new Telegram Mini app open (inside the Telegram), and overlaps on the previous opening mini apps.
There's any why for Telegram to focus on the opening mini app when users click the direct link again?

I am also interested if there is any way to restrict amount of instances for my mini app; Currently I haven't found anything useful in docs.
